# How to create watercolor-like artwork with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to make something like this in Illustrator.

How can I get the fills like it has been drawn? So like, dark to lighter... you see where the brush has been darkest etc.

[image: example]

Comment: Not an easy task, but there are Bristle Brushes.. what have you tired?

Answer (score 1):

Creating something like this in Illustrator from scratch is even bigger effort than painting it. The strokes and fills are so rich that the resulted vector image would contain thousands or tens of thousands nodes. And one must still be able to create all forms, Illustrator doesn't draw them automatically.

A great part of the richness would be got without special effort if one painted this with real colors on real paper. For example the thicker irregular edges of thinly colored areas. In Illustrator every detail must be drawn or defined as brush behaviour.

My suggestion: Get real paper and colors and learn to paint it. Alternatively do it in a painting simulation program. Just one example (= the first try online) https://www.escapemotions.com/experiments/rebelle/index.php

Here are a few random stokes made in the linked website:

[image]

Programs can reduce some errors caused by shaky hands and there's a possibility to duplicate parts, paint in layers and make corrections.

But finally one must be able to create the needed forms. That needs some talent and diciplined practicing to develop the needed skills. Only a competent painter can make something like your example.